# Perl TCP read not timing out

Tags: perl, tcp

I am trying to read data over TCP using the IO::Socket module. I read data either using the '`recv`' function or `<TCP_SOCKET>` . Randomly, I find that the program hangs at that particular line where I am trying to read the data over TCP. The program does not proceed or exit unless I kill it. Why would this happen or how to avoid this from happening?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform a

> select

to determine if there is any data pending before the

> recv

function to avoid a hang. Which platform are you talking about?

Have a look at [select doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html) and [IO::Socket doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket/INET.html).

In terms of other documents, I would recommend either "Network Programming with Perl" from Stein or the classical Stevens "Unix Network Programming".
Practically it is based to use a echo/ping protocol, because not all physical network problems trigger exceptions (e.g. when just unplugging a network cable on one machine, the remote machine does not see it).

Comment: Can you point me to some link which details about this. I am using Active Perl on Windows. Also will this occur if the TCP connection broke in between. Is there a way to identify if the sender broke the connection?

Comment: I would not interpret too much into the error codes - e.g. I overrun the TCP kernel on one machine once and I still saw the server closed the connection as an error code on this machine. Also firewalls in the middle are designed to give out non-meaningful errors for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [IO::Socket::INET](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket/INET.html) and i have had similar problems with timeouts. I solved it using an alarm.

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(  PeerAddr => $HOST,
    PeerPort => $PORT,
    Proto    => 'tcp',
    Timeout  => 20,    # It seems to be ignored.
);


eval {
       local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "TimedOut" };
       alarm 20; # 20 seconds global timeout for receiving.

       $res = <$socket>;

       # your code here. 

       # Disable timeout alarm after receiving.
       alarm 0;
    }

    if ($@) {
       if ($@  eq "TimedOut") {
          print "Warning: timeout receiving\n";
       }
       else {
          print "Error receiving.";
       }
    }
    close ($socket);
```